# How to create instance of ObjectMapper of com.fasterxml.... package in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-databind

How to avoid new keyword should I use @Bean and autowire it in my service class.the same I am working on spring boot application can someone please guide with examples

While autowiring ObjectMapper getting NoBean Exception.. Am running a task in background asynchronously using BackGround Task which implements callable.  In my Service I need Objectmapper but my service class can have multiple instances running in PROD environment. So my question is what is the alternate way of creating or injecting ObjectMapper instance which would be thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

1. Jackson Object Mapper is thread safe, you don't have to worry while working on multithreading.
2. If you want to Autowire this object make sure you do it in Singleton class
3. Also use Constructor Injection.